# How can I select which properties to load and access them Locally

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Reservation entity that has a collection entity called Occupations that holds all of the occupation of the reservation, I want to bind the Reservation entity to a DevExpress GridControl but I don't want to load the Occupations navigation property, I removed virtual but it's still loaded and displayed in the Grid, this is by using `Load()`, what I have tried

```
public IEnumerable<Reservation> GetCurrentReservations()
{
    var DateNow = DateTime.Now.Date;
    context.Reservations
        .Where(r => r.ArrivalDate >= DateNow)
        .Select(r => new
        {
            r.ReservationId,
            r.DepartureDate,
            ...//Other properties
        })
        .Load();

    return context.Reservations.Local;
}
```

But nothing is loaded locally, maybe because I'm creating a list of an anonymous type, so what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you loading locally anyways?  `Load` is usually used when you want to load entities but not to anytihng with them right away.  Since you're binding them immediately, why not just bind to the query:

```
return context.Reservations
              .Where(r => r.ArrivalDate >= DateNow);
```

UPDATE

It seems that the control you are using requires an `IList` rather than just a plain `IEnumerable` (possibly for paging/navigation reasons).  In that case here's a few options to try:

```
return context.Reservations
              .Where(r => r.ArrivalDate >= DateNow)
              .ToList();
```

If you want to cherry-pick columns to load, you may need to project to an anonymous type, switch to Linq-to-Objects, and create new `Reservation` objects in-memory.

```
return
    context.Reservations
        .Where(r => r.ArrivalDate >= DateNow)
        .Select(r => new
        {
            r.ReservationId,
            r.DepartureDate,
            ...//Other properties
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(r => new Reservation
        {
            ReservationId = r.ReservationId,
            DepartureDate = r.DepartureDate,
            ...//Other properties
        })
        .ToList();
```

Note that the new objects will be disconnected from the context so you won't be able to *update* the database from them; you'll need to create `Reservation` objects form the contexts, update the properties, and save them back.

If you're using the MVC or MVVM pattern, you might consider adding a `ViewModel` as a layer of abstraction from your entity layer (which should mimic our database very closely).  The downsides are you load more data than you actually need, and you have to add mapping projections (or use a library like AutoMapper), but it gives you more control over what actually gets loaded to your view (which is part of the goal of MVC).

Comment: What do you mean you can't bind to it?  Have you tried `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()`?

Comment: But this returns an IQueryable and I can't bind to it, when I add ToList() I get an exception that says I can't construct a Reservation in a LINQ to entities query.

Comment: Same exception with AsEnumerable. What I meant is that I can't assign it to a DataSource.

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like that control requires an `IList` for some reason - can you use `ToList` without calling `Load()` or does it still populate the navigation property? (basically adding `ToList` to my answer)

Comment: It will work but I won't be able to select which properties to load...it loads everything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with GridControl, but have you tried adding a [Browsable(false)] attribute on your Occupations property?

Comment: Yeah it works, but that's not what I want to do, I want to be able to select which properties to have in my `Local ` in-memory entity.